# Commissioning VMware machines not visible in MAAS using Autopilot VMware Appliance Setup

Tags: maas

I'm trying Openstack Autopilot VMware Appliance Setup on vSphere and Workstation. After running **autopilot-config** it looks like everything is OK and I get an INFO message that VMware machines are commissioning.

In MAAS however, there isn't any node visible. If I power on one node, PXE boot is working, but I get the following error:

*Could not find kernel image: ubuntu/amd64/generic/xenial/no-such-image/boot-kernel*

Any help to get past this problem is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Ronald

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. go to the images MAAS page and

```
ubuntu@maaslds:~$ maas admin node-groups import-boot-images
Success.
Machine-readable output follows:
Import of boot images started on all cluster controllers
ubuntu@maaslds:~$ maas admin boot-resources import
Success.
Machine-readable output follows:
Import of boot resources started
```

then wait until xenial appears select and apply. after that boot up the VM's and they find a boot image now.